# Prevent duplicate usernames when people register

Tags: php

I will show you my php and html code, here my users register in the database, but I have a question for you. How can I ban the use of the same names? That the names of users in the database are not the same or that one user on several accounts does not log in to the same name

```
<?php


$user = new User($_POST);

$title = $user->username = $user->username = '';

$errors = array('username' => '', 'password' => '');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//check username
if(empty($_POST['username'])){


 $errors['username'] = 'an username is required <br />';

 }else{

 $user->username = $_POST['username'];

 if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $user->username)){

    $errors['username'] = 'Name must be letters and spaces only';

  }


  }

  //check password
  if(empty($_POST['password'])){

  $errors['password'] = 'an password is required <br />';

 }else{

  $user->password = $_POST['password'];

  //Password mora imati najmanje 8 karaktera
 if(strlen($user->password) < 8){


 $errors['password'] = "Password must be atelaast 8 characters long <br>";

  if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/', $user->password)){

     $errors['password'] = 'of at least length 8 <br>containing at least one lowercase   letter<br>and at least one uppercase letter<br>and at least one number';

     }
    }

    }

  if(array_filter($errors)){

  //echo 'errors in the form';


  }else{

  //echo 'form is valid';
  header('Location: login.php');
  $user->save();
  }

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what database you use.

A simpler way would be to just create a unique constraint on the table, this will also enforce it for updates too and remove the need for a trigger. Just do:

Example for MSSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]    
ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_ID_Name_Date] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [Name], [Date]
)
```

and then you'll be in business.
When you create trigger like this in database - there will be impossible to create users with the same Username.